# What’s it called when repeating a word, or sandwiching a word for emphasis?

Tags: greek, emphasis

Basically I need to know what it’s called when you repeat a word in a sentence to make it more memorable or to emphasize it. For example: Bond, James Bond. I know the Greek had a word for it, what is it?

While the term "epizeuxis" is used to describe word repetition, I'm looking specifically for the term describing repetition which "sandwiches" a word or a few words, that is, the term for an ABA-type construction.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a word or phrase to describe repeating the same word (maybe three times) for emphasis?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/507584/is-there-a-word-or-phrase-to-describe-repeating-the-same-word-maybe-three-times) **epizeuxis**

Comment: How do you “sandwich” a word?

Comment: For the edit, see https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/165496/what-is-the-term-for-repeating-something-in-an-a-b-a-fashion-e-g-just-the, which has additional terms.

Comment: Fine spot, Laurel.

Answer (score 0):

**Epizuexis**:

> the immediate repetition of a word or phrase for rhetorical or poetic effect

The example given in the reference is

> the children squealed with glee, with glee

[MW](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/epizeuxis)